# How to include Scypi in buildroot?

Tags: scipy, embedded-linux, buildroot

I want to include Scipy package to my buildroot (2016.11.2) for a custom linux embedded board without pip.

I have tried scanpypi but it fails with `"Error: Could not install package scipy"` message.

I've also included line-profiler package without error.

Thanks for your help
Yvan

Comment: After a search for "scipy cross compilation", this appeared: https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-dev/2016-July/021411.html. Does not sound like good news.

Comment: scanpypi won't work, because setup.py contains main() routine. scipy is has really strange setup and tries to import numpy during the setup. Btw. numpy must be also bumped. I'd suggest that you write to BR mailing list. Perhaps someone will be able to help.